# Firefox 25 & FFOS 1.4 audio

Tags: firefox, audio, mp3, google-translate, firefox-os

I am experiencing an strange behaviour in Firefox 25 and Firefox OS (latest 1.4 nightly). With Firefox 26 the error is gone and everything works perfectly.

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay"> 
    <source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20Firefox" />  
</audio>
```

Firefox 25 Debug Console says something like: Error 404 Mediafile not found. Pausing. Also no controls show up. Ideas?

Comment: There is a try to play the audios, works on Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/dwog58kb/2/ Note: The Google API have inconsistencies on which input it expects, depending on language (en: string, zh: "string"), words or sentences. It's a work to push further. And you may eventually end up needing a library.

Comment: Such this one : https://github.com/hiddentao/google-tts